# Run command with parameters in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

Assume a psuedo command:

```
 psuedocmd.exe
```

It has various parameters like:

```
/scan  /save  /savefolder
```

Now i want to run psuedocmd.exe using batch file.
And i would like to use parameters too.
I am using the following line in batch file

```
psuedocmd.exe /scan /save
```

But in this case psuedocmd.exe is running without the parameters.

Comment: Strange, that should normally work. Maybe psuedocmd.exe needs the `savefolder`-parameter if the `save`-parameter is used? You could try replacing the `/` with `-`. You could also try upper-casing the parameters. Does something basic like `DIR /B` in your batch-script work as intended?

Comment: DIR /B works fine.The order is correct,as it works when i put the same  command on cmd prompt.

Comment: Note, my first comment did not talk about order.. Anyway, we might need to know what that existing non-hypothetical 'mysterious' `psuedocmd.exe` actually is (is it perhaps *[Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/docs/acunetix-wvs-cli-operation/)* ? If it is, I know the answer). This way others can try to reproduce the behavior, or scour the internet about possible bugs that might lead to this (unexpected) behavior.

Comment: Well.. you've been online 4 hours ago.. tell us what pseudocmd.exe is (so I can finally give the answer :P )

Answer (score 0):

Try putting parameters between quotes `"parameter value"`, especially if paths have spaces in them.

Check if the batch text file is not saved in some encoding making your `/` be read as an escape character.

If you want to run the .exe by handing over parameters from the batchfile, don't use variables, just use %1, %2, etc.

```
run.bat /save /folder
```

Where run.bat's contents are:

```
pseudocommand.exe %1 %2
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Hehe, after over half a year, I'm out of patience..</sub>

You must provide the `savefolder` parameter when using the `save` parameter in [Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner](http://www.acunetix.com/blog/docs/acunetix-wvs-cli-operation/), making that line in your batch-file look like:

```
wvs_console.exe /scan "http://www.aaa.com" /save /savefolder "c:\log"
```

Excerpt from the documentation:

```
/scan          Scans a single website.
               Syntax: /scan [url]
               Example: /scan http://testphp.vulnweb.com

/save          Saves scan once scan is finished. The file will be 
                 saved in the location specified by the “/savefolder” switch.
               Syntax: /save

/savefolder    Specify the folder were all the scans and other 
                 scan related files will be saved.
               Syntax: /savefolder [directory]
               Example: /savefolder C:\Acunetix\Scans
```